# Problems with a graphical approach to irrep multiplicities

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Somewhere below a wrong assumption hides very cleverly — but where? I triple checked especially the last parts:

1. All calculations for clebsches etc. of a Lie algebra (or fusion category) can be done graphically — if necessary, declare your scribbles as category theory.
2. Irreps correspond to colored edges in a graph. Nodes are invariant tensors, especially 3-nodes are 3j symbols.
3. To indicate an irrep coming with multiplicity (fusion or weight), just color the nodes.
4. The most simple example coming with a (fusion) multiplicity is Ostrik's non-ribbon category "K0102" (derived from $E_6$) with three elements, $I,A,E$ (I use the "spectrocopists" notation).
5. Rules: $I$ is the identity, $A\otimes A=I$, $A\otimes E=E$, $E\otimes E=I\oplus A\oplus 2E$. (Everything is self-dual and we don't need arrows later.)
6. Thus $E^{\otimes 4}$ has dimension $1^2+1^2+2^2=6$. We can take the $6$ projectors as basis. Especially when exchanging red and green (see below), the result isn't linearly dependent, or we would have only $5$ linearly independent vectors!
7. We have the following 6j symbols (where $A$ is blue, $E$ is black, and the multiplicity of $E$ is red/green, singlets are yellow):
   [image: All 6j symbols of K0102]
8. We can set up the following recoupling matrix $M$ for $E^{\otimes 4}$, which has rank $6$ (see above; evaluation of the graphs is straightforward; J indicates one of the 6j symbols, o the dimension of $E$; 3j gauge is that all theta graphs evaluate to $1$, except the one with red and green which is $0$):
   [image: Recoupling matrix]
9. We solve the system $\operatorname{rank}(M)=6$ with Mathematica.
10. The result is "Nope. No solution. I'm sorry." Which is obvious if you symmetrize $M$ over projectors and their rotations, as well as over a red/green swap. (The root of evil is that mutants — and a red/green swap can generate a mutant — are no longer equal.)
11. We cry like a little baby and ask MO for help.